# How to handle custom exceptions thrown by a filter in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, spring-security

I am new to Spring Security.

I have a piece of code where I check if an Authorization header is passed in a request and I throw an exception if it's missing.

```
public class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private static final String BEARER = "Bearer";

    public TokenAuthenticationFilter(RequestMatcher requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher) {
        super(requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String authorization = request.getHeader("AUTHORIZATION");

        if (!request.getRequestURI().equals(UniversalConstants.LOGIN_PATH)) {
            if (authorization == null || authorization.length() == 0 || !authorization.startsWith(BEARER)) {
                throw new InvalidCredentialsException("Missing authentication token"); //<-----------------
            }

        }

        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
    }
```

I am targeting to handle all exceptions globally so I'm using @ControllerAdvice.

**Note:** I know that @ControllerAdvice will not work for exceptions thrown outside of Controllers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36090215/how-to-gracefully-handle-exceptions-in-spring-security-not-handled-by-controller) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767267/handle-spring-security-authentication-exceptions-with-exceptionhandler), so I have also followed the suggestions in these links.

*RestAuthenticationEntryPoint.java*

```
@Component("restAuthenticationEntryPoint")
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    public RestAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        System.out.println("RestAuthenticationEntryPoint");
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")
    private HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, authException);

    }

}
```

This is how I configure the authenticationEntryPoint:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint()).and().cors().and().csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint(), PROTECTED_URLS)
            .and().authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider())
            .addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class).authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS).authenticated().and().formLogin().disable().httpBasic().disable();

}
```

*CustomExceptionHandler.java*

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({InvalidCredentialsException.class, AuthenticationException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleUnauthorizedError(InvalidCredentialsException e, WebRequest request) {
        String errorMessage = e.getLocalizedMessage();
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(errorMessage, null);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

*InvalidCredentialsException.java*

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
public class InvalidCredentialsException extends RuntimeException {

    public InvalidCredentialsException(String errorMessage) {
        super(errorMessage);
    }

}
```

Upon debugging, I've found that the `resolver.resolveException(...)` in *RestAuthenticationEntryPoint* and the `handleUnauthorizedError(..)` in *CustomExceptionHandler* ***never*** get called.

I wish to handle  `throw new InvalidCredentialsException("Missing authentication token")` in an elegant way and show a decent JSON output in the response.
Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: The stack trace

```
2021-05-20 17:41:29.985 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/public/**']
2021-05-20 17:41:29.986 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user/hello'; against '/public/**'
2021-05-20 17:41:29.986 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2021-05-20 17:41:29.986 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/error**']
2021-05-20 17:41:29.986 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user/hello'; against '/error**'
2021-05-20 17:41:29.986 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2021-05-20 17:41:29.986 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user/hello?username=user&password=user at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2021-05-20 17:41:29.988 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /user/hello' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout'
2021-05-20 17:41:29.988 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2021-05-20 17:41:29.988 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user/hello?username=user&password=user at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2021-05-20 17:41:29.989 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : saved request doesn't match
2021-05-20 17:41:29.989 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user/hello?username=user&password=user at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2021-05-20 17:41:29.989 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user/hello?username=user&password=user at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'TokenAuthenticationFilter'
2021-05-20 17:41:29.989 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/public/**']
2021-05-20 17:41:29.989 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user/hello'; against '/public/**'
2021-05-20 17:41:29.989 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2021-05-20 17:41:29.989 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
2021-05-20 17:41:38.030 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@7fb6b4e0
2021-05-20 17:41:38.030 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2021-05-20 17:41:38.030 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2021-05-20 17:41:38.033 ERROR 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

com.spring.fieldSecurity.Exceptions.InvalidCredentialsException: Missing authentication token
    at com.spring.fieldSecurity.Service.TokenAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(TokenAuthenticationFilter.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
.
.   // more error trace here
.
2021-05-20 17:41:38.034 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/public/**']
2021-05-20 17:41:38.034 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/public/**'
2021-05-20 17:41:38.034 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2021-05-20 17:41:38.034 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/error**']
2021-05-20 17:41:38.034 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/error**'
2021-05-20 17:41:38.034 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : matched
2021-05-20 17:41:38.034 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?username=user&password=user has an empty filter list
2021-05-20 17:41:38.034 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error?username=user&password=user", parameters={masked}
2021-05-20 17:41:38.035 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2021-05-20 17:41:38.035 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2021-05-20 17:41:38.724 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [application/json] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2021-05-20 17:41:38.724 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Thu May 20 17:41:38 IST 2021, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, message=, path=/us (truncated)...]
2021-05-20 17:41:38.726 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2021-05-20 17:41:38.727 DEBUG 24808 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 500
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring security has a filter which is called the [`ExceptionTranslationFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-exceptiontranslationfilter) which translates [`AccessDeniedException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/access/AccessDeniedException.html) and [`AuthenticationException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api//org/springframework/security/core/AuthenticationException.html) into responses. This filter catches these thrown exceptions in the spring security filter chain.

So if you want to return a custom exception, you could instead inherit from one of these classes instead of `RuntimeException` and add a custom message.

I just want to emphasis and it can never be said too many times:

**Providing friendly error messages in production applications when it comes to authentication/authorization is in general bad practice from a security standpoint. These types of messages can benefit malicious actors, when trying out things so that they realize what they have done wrong and guide them in their hacking attempts.**

Providing friendly messages in test environments may be okey, but make sure that they are disabled in production. In production all failed authentication attempts a recommendation is to return a 401 with no additional information. And in graphical clients, generalized error messages should be displayed for instance "*failed to authenticate*" with no given specifics.

Also:

**Writing custom security as you have done is also in general bad practice.** Spring security is battle tested with 100000 of applications running it in production environments. Writing a custom filter to handle token and passwords, is in general not needed. Spring security already has implemented filters to handle security and authentication using standards like `BASIC` authentication and `TOKEN/JWT`. If you implement a non standard login, one bug might expose your application to a huge risk.

- [Username and password authentication in spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-unpwd)
- [Oauth2 authentication in spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2)